# Error during Wildfly8.2/ Jboss EAP 7.0 deployment from Hibernate persistence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, wildfly-8, jboss-eap-7

I started with the migration of **Java 8** and hence i have to change Spring and Hibernate. So i upgraded Spring and hibernate to the below versions. I was able to deploy and the run the code locally on **Tomcat 7**. But getting the below error while trying to deploy it on Wildfly8.0 or Jboss EAP7

I tried the deployment on wildfly and found that internal its trying to invoke hibernate4 bootstrap. Hence i decided to move a little bit upward and try EAP7. EAP7 uses hibernate5 bootstrap. But the error remains the same.

> ```
> 13:47:23,190 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>     name: se-services-persistence
>     ...]
> 13:47:25,624 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."SeviS4Web-1.10.0-UAT.war#se-services-persistence".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."SeviS4Web-1.10.0-UAT.war#se-services-persistence".__FIRST_PHASE__: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not a subtype
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:120)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:102)
>     at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:129)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
> Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not a subtype
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.buildSelector(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:162)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:222)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:365)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:166)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:28)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:40)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.<init>(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:39)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.getBootstrap(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:159)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:242)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$800(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:59)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
>     ... 7 more
> ```

My Pom configuration looks like this.

```
<spring.framework.version>4.2.9.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>  
<spring-security-core-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-security-core-version>

<hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <!-- <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version> -->
   <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-security-core-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-security-core-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-security-core-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate/JPA -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The default Hibernate dependencies should probably be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>` since the container will provide them.

Comment: There are a few tricky exceptions that can occur when your hibernate libraries have not been setup properly. The following error message will occur if you have multiple copies of the hibernate-c3p0 library within application server and your application (e.g WEB-INF...) as well.